# ¿Cómo despliego los componentes de JSF en este proyecto?

Tags: eclipse, jsf

Espero se encuentren bien. Tengo la siguiente pregunta. ¿Porque no me despliega los componentes de JSF en mi Dynamic Web Project ?, solo me despliega la etiqueta de inicio pero no los outputLabel, panelGrid, etc...

[image: Screen shot del codigo]

al momento de hacer el deployment solo arroja el titulo, aquí la imagen.

[image: el resultado al realizar el deploymente con mi servidor glassfish 4]

Answer (score 0):

Bienvenido a SOe.

Por favor, en el futuro no pongas el código como captura de pantalla, ya que si hay que se puede hacer muy pesada su lectura y/o el copiarlo en la respuesta. Revisa el [faq].

En todo caso, en este caso el problema es que usas el tag *<body>* cuando deberías usar *<h:body>*, el motor de JSF no encuentra el XML que busca y no procesa el resto del markup.